# Bug(?) in WPF Command Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, lambda, commandbinding

I'm using WPF (.NET 4.5) and VB.NET with MVVM Light. A `Button` in my `Toolbar` binds to a `RelayCommand` of the underlying VM. The `Button` looks like this in XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=BringLayerForwardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedLayer}">
```

Underlying command is declared like this in the ViewModel:

```
Public Property BringLayerForwardCommand As New RelayCommand(Of Layer) _ 
  (Sub(p) BringLayerForward_Executed(p), _
  Function(p) p IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
              Me.Layers IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
              (p.ZOrder < Me.Layers.Where(Function(l) l.IsFront = p.IsFront).Max(Function(l2) l2.ZOrder)))
```

The Button behaves like this at runtime:

1. It never gets enabled.
2. The breakpoint at `CanExecute` part (2nd parameter of RelayCommand constructor above) never gets hit.
3. If I remove the lambda part from the anonymous function, the breakpoint starts getting hit and the `Button` gets enabled.

After removing the lambda part, the above command looks like this:

```
Public Property BringLayerForwardCommand As New RelayCommand(Of Layer) _
  (Sub(p) BringLayerForward_Executed(p), _
  Function(p) p IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
              Me.Layers IsNot Nothing)
```

Is this a bug or am I really missing something obvious?

### EDIT

Further investigation tells that if I move the entire anonymous function to a regular function, it all starts working just fine. Really seems like a bug.

Comment: sub(**P**) and function(**P**)  is that intentional ?

Comment: @Muds: Yes. `CanExecute` parameter requires a `Boolean`-returning function. `Execute` can take a `Sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you may want some *closure* on this issue ;).

I suspect it was "Issue 7721: Closures not working with RelayCommand" see: http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/changes.

This bug has been fixed in 5.4.1.

Comment: Thanks. That could be it. Thanks for the input.